# Clock divider/ multiplier ( 3/4, x6/4, x8/4) with CD4017s and CD4046

Tags: frequency, frequency-divider

(UPDATED SCHEMATIC) I want to make a clock divider to add to a drum machine. I made this schematics, can anyone confirm it does what it s meant to (multiply the clock from the drum machine by 3/4,6/4,8/4). This is the first time I use these IC and I'm not completely sure.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the Qi's of the left 4017 should be shorted together like those appear to be. Can you show where you got this circuit from?

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! I like that you sat down, drew a clean schematic, and added it to your question! That much work deserves positive feedback, and also a recommendation: Put the chip that handles the input on the left of a schematic, and let the output leave on the right – engineers will always try to read your schematic left-to-right, for "signal flow".

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i just re did the schematic to be much clearer.

Comment: What is the frequency range the PLL should lock on?

Comment: between 10 and 130 Hz according to the tempo knob of the machine.